# Nvarchar to Decimal and then sum it up

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a nvarchar column and I need to convert it to Decimal. I tried the following code and it worked.

```
(CONVERT(decimal(2,2),CellContent,2))
```

Now when I tried to add a sum for the above code it is throwing me error

```
SUM (CONVERT(decimal(2,2),CellContent,2)) - Function Not recognised
```

How do I sum up the cell content field??

Comment: Are you missing a closing parenthesis at the end?

Comment: Oops. Yes I did miss. But now after correcting it . I am getting the following error.  Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

Comment: `decimal(2,2)` allows values from `0.00 - ±0.99`. Sure that's what you need? Doesn't seem like it from the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arithmetic overflow error means SQL can't fit the nvarchar value in the number of positions you specified for the Decimal data type.
What values are you using for the `CellContent` column? 
Try `Decimal(12,2)` maybe?

```
SUM (CONVERT(decimal(12,2),CellContent,2))
```